# Can I specify a AutoLayout constraint on iOS for spacing to the nearest visible neighbor?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, constraints, autolayout

I was curious if it is possible where I can add a constraint to the nearest visible (unhidden) neighbor.

Imagine that I have 3 UIViews:

[view1]-[view2]-[view3]

Lets say there's currently 10px between each views.

What I want is for view1 to be 10px from the nearest visible neighbor. So when I hide view2, view3 will move closer so that there will only be 10px between view1 and view3.

Is this possible via AutoLayout constraints?

Comment: No, it's not. You have to update your constraints manually.

Comment: You can't do this automatically by hiding the middle view,  but you can if you remove it from its superview.

Answer (score 4):

A way to achieve this is to create an `IBOutlet` in the controller and associate your second view’s width constraint with it. Whenever you need to hide `view2`, modify the `constant` property of the constraint instead and set it to `0`. Whenever you need to show the view back, restore the value of the constraint. This way `view3` will dynamically move around.